# PHP Infinite Loop UGH

Tags: php, loops, infinite

I have a cart array for a small ecommerce site i'm building and have run into a loop I can't figure out. If I have 3 different products (not sure if the number of products is relevant over 2) in my cart array (with different ID#'s) and I attempt to update the quantity of the second item, it causes an infinite loop and attempts to continuously add the product again as a new product, rather than updating the existing indentical product.

```
    <?php 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//       Section 3 (if user chooses to adjust item quantity)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if (isset($_POST['item_to_adjust']) && $_POST['item_to_adjust'] != "") {
    // execute some code
    $item_to_adjust = $_POST['item_to_adjust'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    $quantity = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $quantity); // filter everything but numbers
    if ($quantity >= 100) { $quantity = 99; }
    if ($quantity < 1) { $quantity = 1; }
    if ($quantity == "") { $quantity = 1; }
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
              $i++;
              while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
                  if ($key == "item_id" && $value == $item_to_adjust) {
                      // That item is in cart already so let's adjust its quantity using array_splice()
                      array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i-1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $item_to_adjust, "quantity" => $quantity)));
                  } // close if condition
              } // close while loop
    } // close foreach loop
}
?>
```

I just want it to update the quantity of the existing product, not add it as another. Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: It is kinda hard to spot the cause.. but one key note, try using a foreach instead of a while loop Using foreach is optimized for iteration over collections. Also I am not feeling this array (array(.. thing.

Answer (score 1):

when you reach the array_splice command, you are possibly resetting the array pointer, so when the foreach iterates over the next item, it is actually starting from the first item again.

What I suggest you do, is set a flag, after the array_splice and break out of the while loop.  Then test the flag before the next foreach iteration, and break out of that as well if it is set.

i.e.

```
    array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i-1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $item_to_adjust, "quantity" => $quantity)));
    $breakflag=true;
    break;
}
if($breakflag){
    break;
}
```